# Is there a syntax for relative paths to functions wwwroot?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am doing this which works, but it seems a bit of a hack

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"d:\home\site\wwwroot\shared\...", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```

Is there a better pattern to obtain the path of wwwroot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the recommended way would be to use the %HOME% environment variable, which points to your home folder.

Here's what resolving to the path in your example would look like:

```
string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%home%\site\wwwroot\shared\...");
```

Comment: I will give that a try. Where are these "built-in environment variables defined?